# ImportError: cannot import name 'urlpatterns' from 'django'

Tags: django, url-pattern

I am trying to run my first Django application and when I run server I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'urlpatterns' from 'django' (C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py)
```

Why is the following command that I use in `views.py` giving me errors:

```py
from django import urlpatterns
```

As far as I know it should work? I have tried searching the web for an answer but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Well this is apparently *your* views. Share the file that makes this import...

Comment: Hi Willem its actually urls.py inside the main program, ive updated the question

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to import `urlpatterns` from anywhere. `urlpatterns` is a variable that should be *defined* in the `urls.py` file, so:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

# from django import urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('tasks/', include('tasks.urls')),
]
```

There also should *not* be a trailing comma after the closing square bracket (`]`).